# How to use Prometheus' JMXCollector to collect metrics over multiple iterations

Tags: java, multithreading, prometheus, grafana, jmx

I need to create a Java application which collects JMX metrics from a running java process. For this, I am using the [JMXCollector](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/main/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java) class. I couldn't find the option in this to configure it for multiple iterations.

I have a Java wrapper around this to schedule collection after a specified time and for a specified number of iterations. I would like to understand if there is an already existing class that I can use.